# Unable to navigate to second view from Navigation bar Swift UI

Tags: navigation, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

[image]

I want to move to the next view when clicked on "Click me" button. But didn't find any method to do that.

I have tried NavigationLink and they dont work inside navigationBarItems. If I remove navigationBarItems then all items are displayed in the center of screen. I want that at the top of screen.

Answer (score 0):

`NavigationLink` **does** work inside `navigationBarItems`, but you have to omit the button. If you stick a `Button` inside a `NavigationLink`, the button captures the clicks from the user and the navigationLink doesn't receive any events.

Therefore, a working solution is to just use

```
.navigationBarItems(trailing: NavigationLink(destination: Text("Hello, World!")) {
    Text("Click Me!")
})
```